# How to run an url behind the scenes without displaying it in browser?

Tags: c#, asp.net, url

I want to basically run an url which i would be generating behind the scenes without actually displaying it in browser to user...i guess i could use HTTPWebRequest or maybe something similiar to curl?...but i need to really just basically visit/run the generated url? how can i do that ?

Comment: Do you want to run the request from the server side or from the client side?

Comment: want to do it on server side..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [WebRequest](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webrequest(VS.71).aspx) class and its friends.

Other more modern options are the [WebClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(v=vs.110).aspx) class which can be simpler to use in some cases, and the [HttpClient](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx) class which gives you very detailed control over the requests and responses.

Answer (score 1):

one way I have used: post to a hidden iframe

Comment: That's when your own server can't post to the internet or is behind a firewall. This way you leverage the client's browser to do the deed.

Answer (score 1):

There is a good example found here http://www.netomatix.com/httppostdata.aspx

I copied and pasted the example method used to browse to a url:

```
private void OnPostInfoClick(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
{
    string strId = UserId_TextBox.Text;
    string strName = Name_TextBox.Text;

    ASCIIEncoding encoding=new ASCIIEncoding();
    string postData="userid="+strId;
    postData += ("&username="+strName);
    byte[]  data = encoding.GetBytes(postData);

    // Prepare web request...
    HttpWebRequest myRequest = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://localhost/MyIdentity/Default.aspx");
    myRequest.Method = "POST";
    myRequest.ContentType="application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
    myRequest.ContentLength = data.Length;
    Stream newStream=myRequest.GetRequestStream();

    // Send the data.
    newStream.Write(data,0,data.Length);
    newStream.Close();
}
```

Comment: You know, WebClient ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient(VS.80).aspx ) is a much nicer way to send POST data.

Comment: this one is for sending data to the url only. you can omit a few of these lines if you dont want to send data, or use GET instead of POST and send data using the query string.  If you want to read the results, you might have add additional lines between the Write and Close.  If you just want to 'visit' you can simplify this further.

Comment: @Matti yes WebClient seems easier to use. Either way there is many ways to skin the cat.  @kinjal Obviously it can be simplified, it was meant to be as a quick example. I did say that I copied and pasted from netomatix.com for the sole purpose of saving you from having to visit the link to see the sample code, so I haven't bothered 'simplifying' it.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are looking for something like this?

```
Dim request = WebRequest.Create(strUrl)
request.Method = "POST"
request.ContentType = "text/xml" 'change to whatever you need
```

Use the following part optionally to create the body of the request if you are sending this to a web service that needs this, for example

```
Using sw As New StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream())
    sw.WriteLine(HtmlOrXml)
End Using
```

Get the response:

```
Dim response = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)
```

You can then use StreamReader to read the response. You can find more about the classes used above on MSDN.